# how to pass id of selected dropdown in knockout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This is my simple function in knockout.
Here at the last line u can see, **data: ko.toJson(post)**

```
    self.addPost = function () {
    var post = new Post();
    post.Message(self.newMessage());
    return $.ajax({
        url: postApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ko.toJSON(post)
    })
    .done(function (result) {
       self.posts.splice(0, 0, new Post(result));
       self.newMessage('');
   })
   .fail(function () {
       error('unable to add post');
   });
}
```

Now, along with this, i want to pass dropdown selected id something like this

```
data: { id: $("#Locations").val() }
```

**Now, please tell me how to combine these two into one so that i can post message along with selected dropdown id into controller**.This is my controller:

```
   public JsonResult PostPost(Post post, int? id)
    {
        post.PostedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        post.NeighbourhoodId = id;        
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var usr = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == post.PostedBy);
            var ret = new
            {
                Message = post.Message,
                PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                NeighbourhoodId = post.NeighbourhoodId
            };
        return Json( ret,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
    }
```

on my view page,this is the button on which click event i fired addPost function

```
 <input type="button" data-url="/Wall/SavePost" value="Share" data-bind="click: addPost">
```

along with this, dropdown for sending id is something like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Locations", ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId as SelectList, "Select a location", )
          <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#Locations").change(function ()
                  {
                    var locationSelected = $("#Locations").val();
                    var url = '@Url.Action("PostPost", "Post")';
                    $.post(url, { id: locationSelected },
                   function (data) 
                            {
                               });
                            });
                          });
      </script>
```

At this view page, i am doubtful about:

1> at button click,i am calling addPost function and succesfully binding textarea message.But,now, on dropdown selection,should i call same addPost function like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Locations", ViewBag.NeighbourhoodId as SelectList, "Select a location", new { data_bind = "event: { change: addPost}" })
```

I just want to save id of selected dropdown to be sent to controller on input type button click along with Message in text area. i have removed some code to reduce length of question. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your first problem:

```
self.addPost = function () {
    var post = new Post();
    post.Message(self.newMessage());
    return $.ajax({
        url: postApiUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { post: ko.toJSON(post), id: $("#Locations").val() }
});
```

About your second problem, you should not post the controller every time the user changes the dropdownlist's value. I doesn't make sense in my opinion. So, **remove** the "change" function of `#Locations`:

```
 $("#Locations").change(function () {
    var locationSelected = $("#Locations").val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("PostPost", "Post")';
    $.post(url, { id: locationSelected }, function (data) {
    });
 });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply but still there is a problem if i write in textarea and as soon as i select dropdown it hit the controller and id got saved to database with null in message col. i want both to be saved.prob is obvious as i have not pressed input button so post parameter is null at that time.

Comment: as I said, remove the "change function" of `#Locations`.

Comment: as u said i have already done that $("#btnShare").click(function () { with this

Comment: You said "as soon as i select dropdown it hit the controller" - this should not be happening. Only the submit button should post your form

Comment: data: { post: ko.toJSON(post), id: $("#Locations").val() } i think problem is with this line if i use this then message is null and if i use original one then id got saved to be null @Fabio Luz

Comment: I have updated the question full addPost function at top with .done and .fail @Fabio Luz

Comment: you should not "return" the ajax call inside `sef.addPost`. remove the return keyword

Comment: data: ko.toJSON(post), id: $("#Locations").val()  without curly braces if i use this then two rows get inserted in first neighbourhoodId is null and in second message is null .I am pretty sure that both values are not reaching controller together that is why prob occuring hope u know what to do now @Fabio Luz

Comment: your controller has 2 parameters: `Post post, int? id`. So, you have to post 2 values, an object named "post" and an int name "id". So, { post: ko.toJSON(post), id:  $("#Locations").val()  }. Use debugger and see if those values are being sent to the post action

Comment: in Post controller, internal server error status 500 and in dbase id saved but in message col value null saved

Comment: in the console browser you will see the details of this error